# Assign the name of the Folder to the name of a file

Tags: shell, unix

I would like to paste a number of files in a unique file named, for example, "`output.txt`". 
Nevertheless I would like to assign the name of the folder to the name of the output file so that it will be: "`output_<name of the Folder>.txt`".
I have thousands of folders so that the "paste" command will run in a for loop I'm able to write. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by 'paste'?  There's a Unix command `paste` that puts line 1 of each input file on line 1 of the output, then line 2 of each file to line 2 of the output, etc.  Or do you simply mean concatenate (for which there's a command `cat`, of course).  What are you going to provide as arguments to the shell script?  The names of the directories?  Do the directories ever have sub-directories in them?  You have thousands of directories; how many files in a directory?  Do you want to get rid of the original files? Could there be a file `output_<dirname>.txt` already in the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is incredibly unclear.  I'm going to interpret it to mean that you have a large number of directories that all contain a file named 'output.txt', and you want to move those files to a single directory with the original path embedded in the name.  Assuming that the root of the directory tree containing all the files is `/path/to/source` and you want to move them to `/path/to/destination`:

```
find /path/to/source -name output.txt -exec sh -c 'd=$(dirname "$1" | 
    tr / _); cp "$1" "/path/to/destination/output_$d.txt"' sh {} \;
```

Relative paths will work fine as well as absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

I too am unclear about what you want, but `mktemp(1)` has TEMPLATES which might help.